# If a uniquness for all functions exist shouldn't there be uniquness to recursion?

Tags: analysis, functions, recursion, tetration

What I'm specifically saying is every function is definitely unique, as they may be nearly equivalent to another function, for example.

Let's make a table of values for $^{x}2$

(0,1)
(1,2)
(2,4)
(3,16)
(4,65536)

The recursive relation is of course, $a_2=2^{a_1}$, if $^{x}2$ is described as this recursively is it possible to describe these points in others ways that don't simplify to $a_2=2^{a_1}$

This may sound obvious, but if every function is unique analytically, than is a recursive function unique.

So does $^{x}2$ have a unique recursive function, or are there other ways of describing it recursively,without simplifiying it to $a_2=2^{a_1}$?

I'm having trouble explaining this, hopefully this could be clarified!

Comment: $\ln(e^x)$ is equivalent to $x$ on the entire real line.

Comment: True, but is there a way of describing without cancelling inverses, basically, this is an identity, which can be simplified to x, but is there only one way to define anything that isn't.... I'll edit this ,sorry about that!

Comment: @Conifold: That was an extremely major revision to the question. I have rolled it back. If you would like to keep it you can place it in your answer. If OP would like to keep it then E may choose to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you're trying to say, but I'm also not sure if it is possible to say with any rigor. I think that you essentially want to essentially know whether "simplification" is in some sense "complete": so that if two recurrence relations which appear in different forms always give the same outputs given the same inputs, then they can both be simplified down to a single, "standard" form.

---

There is a weaker statement of your question which is answerable.

> If two functions appear different but always give the same outputs for the same inputs, then is it true that the two functions are always equal?

The answer to this question is **yes**. There is nothing particularly deep about this fact; in fact it is simply a consequence of the definition. [Warning: this definition is very technical. If you want to understand it completely you should read the last line first, and then the rest in order, very slowly.]

> We say the ordered triple $(D,C,R)$ is a *function* if
>
> - $R$ is a *relation* from $D$ to $C$, that is, $R$ consists of ordered pairs $(d,c)$ such that $d\in D$ and $c\in C$.
> - $R$ is *total*, that is, for any $d\in D$ there is a $c\in C$ such that $(d,c)\in R$
> - $R$ is *single-valued*, that is, for any $d\in D$, there is not more than one $c\in C$ such that $(d,c)\in R$.
>
> For ease of reading, we give the function a name $f$, and write $f(d)=c$  instead of $(d,c)\in R$.

The point of this definition is that the *form* of the function is totally irrelevant: the *only* thing that matters is the input-output pairs.

I will briefly address something which I have been sidestepping thus far about your question. Recursion, so long as each step is uniquely specified [i.e. you're not solving for, say, $a_7$ using anything like $(a_7)^2=a_6$] is no more powerful than function notation. And if each step is not uniquely specified, you have bigger problems :)

By this I mean: recursion takes every natural number and (somehow) turns it into a number in the reals. This is an operation that is completely captured by the formal definition of a function. That is why I have shifted from recursive language to functional language. From this abstract perspective, there is no difference at all.

---

However, the question you actually asked is much, much, much harder. For instance, consider the following special case of your question:

> Suppose $f(x)= x+\displaystyle\max_{\zeta(s)=0}\Re(s)$, where $\zeta(s)$ is the analytic continuation of $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k^s}$. Is this function equal to $f(x)=x+\frac12$?

This question is equivalent to the [Riemann Hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis), a century-old unsolved problem with a million dollar bounty for its proof.

You may notice I am still using functional language, although we have descended from the lofty place we were before. This is because from an algorithmic viewpoint, functions are a special case of recursion. Given any function, you can write $a_n=f(n)$; this is a zeroth-order recurrence relation. **The point is that even in the function case— at the *zeroth level* of complexity— the question is still impossibly hard.**

(In fact, nearly every unsolved problem in mathematics can be "turned into" a function in a similar way— although some would require a lot more cleverness than others.)

---

If questions about algorithms, reducibility, and fundamental complexity really turn you on, you might be interested in *Descriptive Set Theory*. If your question has any satisfying answer, it'll probably be found there. Fair warning, *a lot* of DST  is very technical. If you want to go this route you might consider asking another question looking for a reference. I would give you one myself, but I have not in the field much, and so I don't know what books would be accessible to beginners.

Comment: @Arbuja: I'm not sure it's *better*, but it's different, yes :P

Comment: Thank you, hopefully I'll understand mathmatics much more detail. I still have a lot of time:).

Comment: @Arbuja: Thank you :) One thing I want to mention for the future if you plan to become more involved in MSE: I appreciate the accepted answer marker, but it's not very nice to give it to somebody and then take it away (as you did to Conifold). I admit that I swing pretty far in the other direction— I typically wait an entire week to accept answers to my questions. But I think in general one should not accept an answer on the same day that you ask the question.

Comment: Wow! I should have known that I can only up one person, silly me, sadly "best answer" of course means one only. I'll be more  careful next time. I apoligise @conifield if I took anything from you. Thanks Eric for notifying me of this!

Answer (score 1):

Any relation that produces this sequence can of course be 'ultimately' simplified to  $a_{n+1}=2^{a_n}$ just because this is how consecutive elements in the sequence are related. You do not however specify which identities are 'allowed' in a simplification. There are analytic functions that vanish on all integers, $\sin(\pi x)$ for example, so $a_{n+1}=2^{a_n}+\sin(\pi a_n)$ will produce the same sequence because all $a_n$ are integers, but as functions $2^x$ and $2^x+\sin(\pi x)$ do not reduce to each other. Also, 
in general there is no algorithm to determine if two analytic expressions represent the same function, or can be reduced to each other based on a given list of identities.

Comment: I would argue that the two functions you specified do, in fact, reduce to each other (as functions $\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$), since $\sin(\pi a_n)$ "reduces" to $0$. [FWIW: I think your answer is a good start but I think it doesn't address enough of the subtlety.]

Comment: Well it was worth both of your helps, Eric, if you have a better way of explaining maybe you could. Thanks! Yes, it kind of vague.

Comment: One would expect allowed identities to include standard exponential, logarithmic, trigonometric, etc., formulas. Based on those only $2^x+\sin(\pi x)$ will not reduce to $2^x$.